# Editor Template for Nullable Boolean Dropdown list not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a property called Critical which is a Nullable Bool for instance "NULL, True, False) stored in a tabe as Critical bit null. User can select "Yes/No or blank (which will store the value as NULL)

I created an Editor template in Shared/EditorTemplates called FriendlyBool.cshtml

```
@model bool? 
@using System.Web.Mvc   
@{   
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();  
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" }); 
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value }); 
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value });
 }
```

In my view I call this editor template

```
 <div class="bodyContent">
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Critical")
        </span><span class="rightContent">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.critical, "FriendlyBool")
        </span>
    </div>
```

When I run my view, I see the default dropdown with values as "Not Set, "True" and "False".  Why would my editor template not display?

Comment: Your `EditorTemplate` does not do anything except create `List<SelectListItem>();` - it does not display anything (nothing generates any html)

Comment: Well it is rendering the default SelectList and not the one from the editor template

Comment: There is nothing in the `EditorTemplate` to render at all (just creating a new `SelectList` does not mean that it gets rendered). At the very least the template needs to include `@DropDownListFor(m => m, selectlist)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  :) got it, its rendering now. Just one more thing, when I submit my form, MVC validation is preventing the form to be submitted unless I select a value from drop down list. The whole reason to add a blank value to the dropdown list so users dont have select a value and choose blank. How can I prevent MVC to not make the dropdown selection, its high lighting the dropdown in red.

Comment: Then remove the first `SelectListItem` and use `@DropDownListFor(m => m, selectlist, "")` and ensure the property does not have a `[Required]` attribute

Comment: that works 100%, Please post your solution as an answer and I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `EditorTemplate` is not generating any html (just creating a `SelectList`). Change the template to

```
@model bool? 
@using System.Web.Mvc   
@{   
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();  
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true" }); 
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false" });
} 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, selectList, "")
```

Also ensure you property does not have the `[Required]` attribute.

Side notes

1. Use the overload of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts a `labelOption`
   to generate the `null` option
2. There is no need to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`.
   You are binding to a property, so if the value if `null`, the first
   option will be selected, or if its `true` the second option ("Yes")
   will be selected.

Answer (score 6):

Extending the answer from alireza to cater for passing htmlAttributes:

```
@model bool?
@{
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "(Any)", Value = String.Empty, Selected = !Model.HasValue},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value}
    };
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, selectList, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.critical, new
{
    htmlAttributes = new { @class = "variables-filter", disabled = "disabled" }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update your property from database use this:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@model bool?
@{
var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = String.Empty,Selected = !Model.HasValue });
selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true",Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value });
selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value });}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, selectList)
```

Also you can use `[UIHint("FriendlyBool")]` attribute for your property to use this tamplate